# Store data in Firebase as JSON object

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, firebase

So I am working on a small web app and I am using Firebase for the back-end. It's a small chat application and I am trying to store the messages of a person in the following form:

```
{ "John" : {0: "hello",1:"how are you?".2:"what are you doing?" }}
```

I am storing the person's name in a variable called my_name. My Firebase reference is called ref. Say I set my_name as,

```
var my_name = "John";
```

and then do

```
ref.set({my_name : {0:"Hello"}});
```

It stores the data as

```
{my_name : {0:"Hello"}}
```

instead of

```
{"John" : {0:"Hello"}}
```

How can I store it so that it uses the assigned value of my_var ?

Comment: Why is the chat data being saved as an array? That's probably going to cause issues later. When storing chat data like this, a better option may be to  push() to generate node names and store the messages as a key:value pair within each node. Doing it like that will enable you to store who the message is from and to as well as timestamp, perform queries and other details. Also, you have a period in your example (.2) instead of a comma.

Answer (score 3):

Try putting brackets around your property name like so:

```
var my_name = 'John';

ref.set({
  [my_name]: { 0: "Hello" }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a JS object like this

```
var obj = {};
obj[my_name] = "{ 0: "Hello" }";
```

then save this to Firebase

```
ref.set(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your {} in set.

```
var car = {type:"Fiat", model:"500", color:"white"};

        function writeData() {
            firebase.database().ref('cars/'+ dateToInsert).set(
                car
            );
```

That save: 
 
type:"Fiat" 
 
model:"500" 
 
color:"white"

```
        function writeData() {
            firebase.database().ref('cars/'+ dateToInsert).set({
                car
            });
```

That save:

car: 
 
- type:"Fiat" 
 
- model:"500" 
 
 - color:"white"